# google maps api location of user + another 3-4 locations

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have searched through the web and have read all related questions on Stackoverflow regarding google maps api but I'm kinda overwhelmed and can't choose which one.

What I want to do is:

User get's on my page and I get his location than I display him 3-4 different locations of some shops near the user.

I already have the locations of the shops I just want to display the fastest way from the user to the shop.

Which google api should I choose?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this: 
[Google maps directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple)

You can find working sample under that link.

for user location use this:

[user geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation)